# Asset Library- grayed out columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, view, asset-library

I have an asset library to store videos, but I cannot update the All Item table view to show the default description field in the table.  In designer, I can remove "explicit=true" from the column, but that causes an error if I want to modify the view online. I also cant just create a new description column to use, because the edit form uses the original. (The edit form is the only place I can see the description, it doenst even show up in the view item form)

The description field an several others are greyed out in the modify view page. Does anyone know how to get the description to be visible?

Comment: I guess you need some permissions level higher than the current permission level, what permission level you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing explicit=true to explicit=false in sharepoint designer fixes this problem. You just cant remove the whole explicit statement.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Admin , if you have Design or Full Control permissions over the site or specific asset library.

Check if there is any break in inheritance if you have specific permissions for the asset library.